# Is [[nodiscard]] any different from [[gnu::warn_unused_result]]?

Tags: c, gcc, unused-variables, nodiscard, c23

I had some code that used the GCC extension `[[gnu::warn_unused_result]]` (a.k.a. [`__attribute__((__warn_unused_result__))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributeshttps://)).  Now I attempted to use C2x's `[[nodiscard]]` and I got an incomprehensible error.  I'm not sure if the usage of `[[nodiscard]]` is considerably different from the old GCC attribute, or if it's just a bug in GCC:

```
$ cat warn_unused_result.c 
[[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
int foo(void);

[[gnu::warn_unused_result]]
int bar(void);


int foo(void)
{
    return 1;
}

int bar(void)
{
    return foo();
}
```

```
$ cc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c2x -c warn_unused_result.c
```

```
$ cat nodiscard.c 
[[nodiscard]]
int foo(void);

[[nodiscard]]
int bar(void);


int foo(void)
{
    return 1;
}

int bar(void)
{
    return foo();
}
```

```
$ cc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c2x -c nodiscard.c          
nodiscard.c:2:1: error: 'nodiscard' attribute directive ignored [-Werror=attributes]
    2 | int foo(void);
      | ^~~
nodiscard.c:5:1: error: 'nodiscard' attribute directive ignored [-Werror=attributes]
    5 | int bar(void);
      | ^~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

```
$ cc --version
cc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Obviously, I'm not ignoring the return value of any of the functions.

That `1` is never lost (the callers of `bar()` are in a different translation unit, which might be the problem triggering GCC's behavior?...)

Comment: Ahh, it seems that it is not yet implemented by GCC, and therefore ignored.  However, it seems to at least consider it differently than a random attribute such as `[[foobar]]`, because the error is different `attribute directive ignored` vs `attribute ignored`; probably because it is understood to be C++.  This is what happens when you attempt to use unreleased features :)

Comment: Yeah, I get the same warnings when using [gcc v10.2](https://godbolt.org/z/Y5z9nWT5E), but they disappear when using [gcc v11.1](https://godbolt.org/z/8fYWbTzvj)

Comment: @yano Thanks! Upgrading to gcc from debian experimental (gcc 11.1.0) silenced the warnings :)

Comment: However... Now I found an actual bug in `[[nodiscard]]`.  Time to report it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that C2X will likely suggest to implementations that the warning can be easily suppressed:

> Evaluation of a nodiscard call as a void expression […] is discouraged unless explicitly cast to `void`.

By contrast, GCC's implementation of attribute `warn_unused_result` warns even in those cases:

- [can't disable `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25509)
- [`(void)` cast doesn't suppress `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66425)